# Artisan::call('config:cache') not working from controller. What could the possible way to run this from controller

Tags: php, config, laravel-6

I'm trying to run config:cache and route:cache from controller on Laravel 6.

I don't want to run this commands from shell for end users.

But when I run them by `Artisan::call('config:cache')` and `Artisan::call('route:cache')` they are creating boostrap\cache\config:php and boostrap\cache::route.php. but not actually working.

Comment: Why do you need to cache config or routes on every request to the controller?

Comment: not on every request, this could be a option for caching them. rather than running them via shell

Comment: Even if you do it once while making your code live, it should be enough.

Comment: If you still wish to do it, you can do it once in your HTTP request lifecycle with a combination of service provider and artisan console structures. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/artisan#retrieving-input  https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/providers

Answer (score 0):

It is also possible to use Artisan from a route in `web.php`.

```php
Route::get('config', function () {
    \Artisan::call('cache:clear');
    \Artisan::call('storage:link');
    \Artisan::call('view:clear');
    \Artisan::call('route:clear');
    \Artisan::call('config:clear');
    dd("Success..! OK");
});
```